# How to display a webview in a landscape viewcontroller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `viewcontroller` which contains only a `webview`. However, contents of this webview are very wide, so I need to show this in `landscape` mode.

The question is how to rotate the webview or whole view controller?

I tried to change the `orientations` like this but didn't work:

```
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .LandscapeLeft
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Landscape
}
```

Comment: You want to run it always in Landscape ?

Comment: Yes want to lock that one specific viewcontroller in landscape.

Comment: override shouldAutorotate in view controller and return true

Comment: my answer should work if you want to lock it on a single viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

in AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock the orientation for that ONE page only, do the following:

Add this to your ViewDidLoad() on the page you want to have in Landscape only.

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appdelegate.shouldRotate = false

            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Landscape.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

Add the following functions in your class.

```
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        // Lock autorotate
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape]
    }


    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        // Only allow Portrait
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Landscape
    }
```

When you leave the page, unlock it with adding the following code:

```
   override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appdelegate.shouldRotate = true
    }
```

In your AppDelegate, put the following code:

```
var shouldRotate = true

    //MARK: - Func to rotate only one view controller
    func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if (shouldRotate == true){
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
        }

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape

    }
```

Comment: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'shouldRotate'. Are you sure about that method?

Comment: added some code for the appdelegate, forgot to put it in there, sorry :D

Comment: @TheCook did it work? If so, please mark the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It work perfectly:

Put this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

**and**

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
 {
    return true
}
```